# Convert string to date with date and time together in Hive

Tags: datetime, hive, type-conversion, hiveql

I need convert string to datetime (date and time together).

I try this:

```
cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190303164305', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))) as date) as date_data_chamada
```

timezone: Brazil

But this way returns just date, like this: 2019-03-03, and I need: 2019-03-03 16:43:05

Thanks!

Full code:

```
INSERT INTO p_b.este PARTITION (dt_originacao_fcdr)
SELECT
tp_registro_fcdr,
seq_registro_fcdr,
tp_cdr_fcdr,
dt_atendimento_fcdr,
data_atendimento_completa_fcdr,
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(data_atendimento_completa_fcdr, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")as timestamp) as date_data_atendimento_fcdr,
hr_atendimento_fcdr,
duracao_atend_fcdr,
hr_originacao_fcdr,
duracao_total_fcdr,
duracao_chamada_tarifada_fcdr,
st_chamada_fcdr,
fim_sel_orig_fcdr
FROM p_b.norm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `date` casting and `to_date` functions as you are expecting timestamp!

**`Example:`**

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190303164305', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as date_data_chamada;
```

**`RESULT:`**

```
2019-03-03 16:43:05
```

---

If you use **`to_date`** or **`cast('string' as date)`** then hive results only **`date(yyyy-MM-dd)`**!

**Ex:**

```
hive> select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190303164305', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) as date_data_chamada;

--2019-03-03
```

Comment: but the datatype of date_data_chamada is date, using timestamp is string. Am I right? Even using timestamp, still return just date. (2019-03-03)

Comment: Thanks, @shu. But i am doing exactly what you told me and nothing change.
My return: 
data_atendimento_completa_fcdr      20190303131615 (column that i am trying convert)
date_data_atendimento_fcdr             2019-03-03 (return with your code)

Comment: That works with a insert function? Because, with select it worked... insert dosent (my case)

Comment: As discussed in chat, the type defined in final table is `date` type and while inserting data into table hive will insert only `yyyy-MM-dd` only, after changing to `timestamp` type fixed the issue!

Comment: i need the difference beteween two dates (timestamp), what a type i should use for this return? ex. timestamp_1 - timestamp_2 = difference

Answer (score 0):

Pass the second argument *format string* to `from_unixtime`. Note that the returned type is `string`.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190303164305','yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```